# Error: `thread_id_key != 0x7777' failed. Aborted (core dumped) when I start my node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, coredump

I have problem when start my server on `npm run server`, I receive this error:

node: ../src/coroutine.cc:134: void* find_thread_id_key(void*): Assertion `thread_id_key != 0x7777' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

My work team, update the node project to 16.13 and NPM to 8.1.0. And I'm only person who has this problem.

I use *npm n* to update my node.

I tried run `npm rebuild` and reinstall my node from scratch, but the problem persist.

When I roll back the version, the server goes back to run, but I need use Node 16.13 in the project. Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you are using this: https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/451. Otherwise, try giving more information about the node modules you are using.

Comment: Hello, we don't use fibers. The project is complete system, not API.. So we using much modules. So, is there any other module likely to cause this error?

Comment: @CaioMontenegro and likely others, even though you aren't directly using `fibers` it might happen that on of your dependencies uses it. Check package-lock.json or do a global search. In NPM's dependency hell you never know... and often you don't know.

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the `fibers` package from your project, as it's don't support 16.x versions of node.js

## NPM

`npm uninstall fibers`

## YARN

`yarn remove fibers`

If you still have trouble after removing it, you might clear some files to flush old Data:
`rm package-lock.json && rm -R ./node_modules && npm install`