# I am getting Assertion failed: (thread_id_key != 0x7777), function find_thread_id_key, file coroutine.cc, line 134. zsh: abort

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I already try this
`npm uninstall fibers && rm package-lock.json && rm -R node_modules && npm install`
but still facing the same issue

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/451 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71153774/421195.   `There's a note on the front page README about this. Fibers will not be supported on nodejs v16.x or higher.`Follow the instructions to uninstall fibers.